# Can I regard WebAssembly Text Format as an another kind of programming language?

Tags: webassembly

Can I regard WebAssembly Text Format (.wat) as an another kind of programming language which was designed based on s-expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically it is a programming language. However, it is very low-level and verbose, and not designed to manually write large programs in. Its primary purpose is to display Wasm code in tools like debuggers in human-readable form.